# Recurrence in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am about to create program in Prolog that returns list of values from recurrence:

```
f(1) = 3, f(2) = 2, f(n) = f(n-1) * f(n-2)
```

E.g

```
 rekur(5, S). -> S = [3, 2, 6, 12, 72]
```

I tried to solve it using:

```
rekur(2,[3,2]).
rekur(X,[H|T,M]):- X1 is X-1, rekur(X1,[H1,T1,M1], H1 is T*M.
```

Which has been proven to be completely wrong. Could you demonstrate the solution for this example? The explanation is highly appreciated. I have found that I have no idea how Prolog works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `[H|T,M]` doesn't make sense, and should probably be `[X,Y|T]` or something like that, if you're trying to show a list of at least two elements `X`, `Y`, and the "rest" `T`. You also have at least one other typo in your code (missing right paren on the `rekur` call). Could you please update your question with the exact code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A major problem is probably that `[H|T,M]` is not a valid list. In fact a list in Prolog looks like what most programmers consider a linked list: it is a tuple containing a reference to the element (called the *head*) and a reference to the next tuple (called the *tail*). There is a special list `[]` which means end of list. `[3,2]` is simply syntactical sugar for `[3|[2|[]]]` which is actually nice formatting of `[](3,[](2,[]))`.

Because of this linked list concept, you cannot (nor syntactically nor on *O(1)* access the last elements).

That's why Prolog usually works the other way around: you generate the head of the list, and by using recursion, the remainder of the list is filled in correctly. For your `rekur/2` clause, you can work with two accumulators `A` and `B` that somehow store the next elements that will be emitted in the list. Furthermore you use the `N` (the length of the list to be generated) as loop counter. For example:

```
rekur(N,L) :-
    rekur(N,3,2,L).

rekur(N,_,_,[]) :-
    N <= 0,
    !.
rekur(N,A,B,[A|T]) :-
    N > 0,
    C is A*B,
    N1 is N-1,
    rekur(N1,B,C,T).
```